# Rails: generate scaffold with enum as field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, enums

I want to run `rails g scaffold` command to generate my billing plans table.
I want it like this:

```
id: string
name: string
description: string
status: enum["enabled", "disabled", "coming_soon"]
price: integer
```

How can I use that generator to accomplish this? I don't know what to put here `rails g scaffold BillingPlans name:string description: string price:integer status: <My awesome enum type>`

Using:

- Rails 7
- Postgresql

Answer (score 1):

To straight up answer your question:

```
rails g scaffold BillingPlans name:string description: string price:integer status:integer
```

The enum would be a normal integer field combined with adding `enum status: [:enabled, :disabled, :coming_soon]` in the BillingPlans model. (Really nice blogpost about this -> https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum)

Now how I would personally do this, don't use scaffold. It creates so many files, just simply create a migration and write everything manually. You'll have full control of every line of code this way.
Second, I honestly don't know what the upside is of having an enum field instead of a normal string that is validated to be one of the 3 values you mentioned...

Comment: I prefer using enums instead of String just for more security.
With rails 7 you can manage enums in a better way: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41469
I think I will create view, controller, model and migration one by one instead of using scaffold because of what you said!

Comment: Oh cool, wasn't aware of this (I'm still on Rails 5...)